# log file question

Tags: syslog

I have a program that put out a log file to the `/var/log/myfiles/` directory. 
these files are kept small in size and the file name is incremented by number . at the end of the day I want to cat the last file to a report. 
I'm drawing a blank on doing this. I can find the file but its not working in a script.

```
/var/log/myfile/master
/var/log/myfile/master.1
/var/log/myfile/master.2
/var/log/myfile/master.3
```

Comment: in your example, should we assume that the `.3` version is the "last"?

Comment: Are you really using [tag:syslog] to write these files? And `logrotate` to cycle them? If so, then `master` would be more recent than `master.3`, and so `master` should be the "last" file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the file you want ("last file") is the one with the highest numeric extension, you could use [zsh's powerful globbing capabilities](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn):

```
zsh -c 'cat /var/log/master.*(oe['REPLY=${REPLY##*.}']n[-1]) > report'
```

The wildcard/glob expansion is:

- `/var/log/master.*` -- match files that start with `/var/log/master.`
- `( ... )` -- defines the "glob qualifier"
- `o` -- order the results
- `e['REPLY=${REPLY##*.}']` -- the results to sort are given by stripping the leading text through the first period, turning, for example, `/var/log/myfile/master.3` into just `3`
- `n` -- order the results numerically, not alphabetically
- `[-1]` -- after sorting the results, pull out only the last element (largest element)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I changed the file names to include date and time stamp. Easier to identify and extract the needed data.

```
Master-20-Jan-2019-18:20.log
Master-20-Jan-2019-18:45.log
Master-20-Jan-2019-19:18.log
```